# Marshalling information from JSON into MVC model classes

Tags: php, json, model-view-controller, kohana

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP MVC - Convert JSON to Model data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902971/php-mvc-convert-json-to-model-data)

Is there an easy way using vanilla PHP, a PHP library, or Kohana to easily marshall information from a json encoded object into a Kohana MVC model object? The json_encoded object has the same fields as the model object, but none of the functionality. Is there a generally accepted way of avoiding this silly dance?

It just feels like I am constantly writing code to move data around with code like:

```
$array = json_decode(returnsObject());
$model = Model::factory("model");
$model->field1 = $array['field1'];
$model->field2 = $array['field2'];
.....
```

Now obviously I have this in a method, but it seems outlandish that there is not a better method of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easy way.

Controller in MVC design pattern is responsible **only** for extracting data from users request and passing it to model layer and current view. Your code example is actually a almost acceptable implementation of controller's action ... that's of course, if you ignore the factory method anti-pattern and referring to [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) as "models".

You could extent the [`Request`](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.2/master/classes/kohana/request.php) class and add the method that extracts data from JSON string before returning it, but it would violate [*single responsibility principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: Could you explain that last sentence a bit more? I am a little confused reading your answer.

Comment: @thatidiotguy do you mean the part about domain object or the factory method?

Comment: The domain object, sorry you edited right after I submitted comment.

Comment: The problem is partially related to fact that CodeIgniter was basically a Rails clone and the core ideas in Ko3 haven't really changed. It implemented the same perversion of original MVC pattern. In a proper implementation of MVC pattern you have two layers: presentation layer (which might contain controllers, views and templates) and model layer. The model is not a class or any single object. It is a layer which contains storage abstractions and structures, that encompass domain business logic (usually domain objects and services).

Comment: To be clear, the model does have functionality other than just a variable mule. If all it was doing was holding information, then the result of the `json_decode` function would return just what I need.

Comment: did you READ the link, that explained what domain objects are ?

Comment: Yes, are you saying that calling my "model" object a model in MVC lingo, is the problem you are pointing out with the framework?

Comment: Kinda both. It is a misnomer. But the historical lack of isolation between domain business logic and presentation layer is a flaw in framework. When you have interaction between two+ "models", you put it in the controller. But this is actually a part of business logic, that should stay in model layer (encapsulated in services). It is possible to implement a proper separation, but it is not a common practice and most of people are not aware of this being a problem. Thus turning this lack of separation in the main cause for fat controllers and skinny "models".